# Modal button only shows first user in database

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I am creating a database and I am trying to make a button that shows the users ticket information. Whenever I click the button I want it to say the individual persons name, but no matter which user I click on it only shows the first users name and not the name of the person who's button I clicked on. Here is the code for the modal button

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count ==0){
        $output = 'There was no search result!';
}else{

    $counter=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $fname = $row['f_name'];
        $lname = $row['l_name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $password = $row['password'];
        $userID = $row['userID'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        if($status == 'Active'){
            $classStatus='label-success';
        }else{
                $classStatus='label-danger';
        }
        $output.='<tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="tv8" href="#"><img src="images/tv8.png" alt="Send TeamView 8 Link to Email" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
                        <img src="images/cert.png" alt="Send Certification to Email" style="width:30px;height:30px;"> 
                    </td>
                    <td>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '</td>
                    <td id='.++$counter.'>' . $email. '</td>
                    <td>' . $userID . '</td>
                    <td>' . $password . '</td>

                    <td><h4><span class="label ' .$classStatus.'">'.$status.'</span></h4></td>   

<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</button></td><!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ticket Information</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . ' ticket info will be found here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I make this code show different peoples names when I click the button instead of just the first person listed in the database?

Comment: are you using jquery ajax to populate the $fname and $lname variables?  If so what query is being run on the db?

Comment: If u're talking modal n clicks, then you should be looking at Ajax implementation

Comment: Yeah i am using jquery ajax to populate the variables, http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Then please add the relevant code to the question (js for open modal / fetch data and PHP to fetch and return data)

Comment: Well somewhere you need to be looping otherwise how do you do anything more than once

Comment: I added more code, I'm not sure if that is what you guys are looking for. Sorry for the confusion I am pretty new to this

Comment: It looks like the id you're using "myModal" is part of the while loop and being used more than once. You'll need to change that to a class

Answer (score 0):

Use that $counter variable you've set to distinguish between the Mymodal ids.  Change your button to this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal' . $counter . '">
```

and your modal:

```
<div id="myModal' . $counter . '" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

I wouldn't do it like this myself but this should solve your problem

Comment: No problem, happy to help